# Python usage: [--summaryfile] file [file ...]

Tags: python

Greeting all!

I'm learning Google's Python class on my own. I have one quick question about the Baby Names Exercise.

In the py file provided, there are lines like this:
if not args:
    print 'usage: [--summaryfile] file [file ...]'
    sys.exit(1)

I can understand it wants to show you what to type in cmd when using the code. However the format of "[--summaryfile] file [file ...]" confuses me. What does the square brackets in "[--summaryfile]" and "[file ...]" mean? Lists? Or something else? What should I type in the Windows cmd when running the code? Some examples would be very helpful.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that those parts are optional.  You can supply or omit the option name `--summaryfile`.  Then you supply a list of as many files as you want.

This is *ancient* command description syntax, going back to the days of IBM mainframe operating systems in the 1960s.  Most documentation assumes that you've seen (or can find) a description somewhere, and most supply it in the front of the global reference manual ... wherever that might be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it the same with "[file...]"? What's the difference between the "file" in the middle and the "[file...]" in the end? Why there are "..." in the brackets in the end?

Comment: Yes.  `file` outside the brackets means that the first one is required; the ellipsis means that you can have as many additional files as you want; it denotes a series of arbitrary length.

Comment: So can I say that "file" and "[file...]" are actually the same thing, not like upper and lower directories? In that case it can actually be written as 'file1 [file2 file3 file4...]', is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that 1-2-3-4 syntax is just right.  Merely `[file ...]` would mean that you don't *have* to specify any files at all.

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In command line application documentation, square brackets usually denote optional arguments (that goes beyond Python).